# Android Location Chaged event is not fired using GPS Provider

Tags: android

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 minute

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;


    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,enter code here
            0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
}




/*************************** Andriod Manifest ****************************** Has this tag also

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Attached is my code. It is returning isGpsEnabled as true, but OnLocationChanged event is not fired, Please suggest. I need it very important. If I use the same code using "Network provider" it is working and reurning current location latitude & longitude.

Comment: Are you running this code on an emulator or on a actual phone?

Comment: Thank you @Smalesy for the quick reply, I'm connecting phone to the system and running the code

Comment: did you have success using a phone?

Comment: Yes, using phone I got success for isGPSEnabled , but in the phone it is still saying that 'Searching for GPS'.  As I mentioned earlier, it is successfully giving the current lat and long when I'm saying 'Network Provider' instead of GPS provider